# React .- reduce() within JSX not rendering

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have following code within render method:

```
return (<select>
{[...Array(24).keys()].reduce((acc, item) => `${acc} <option value="${item}">${item}<option>`, '')}
</select>);
```

acc variable contains all options, and reduce() function has implicit return but no options are displayed. What is explanation behind this?

I was able to make this work with .map(), I'm just curious what is the problem with the reduce function in the above example.

```
<select>
{[...Array(24).keys()].map(hour => {
return <option value={hour} key={hour}>{hour}</option>
})
}
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: In your reduce you are not returning an Array of options but a string

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the output in the inspector, you will see that you have a `<select>` which contains a text node. This is because you are building a *string* in your reducer. React renders strings as text, regardless of their content.

If you wanted to use `reduce`, then one option would be to do something like this:

```js
ReactDOM.render(<select>
{[...Array(24).keys()].reduce((acc, item, index) => [
  ...acc, 
  <option key={index} value={item}>{item}</option>
], [])}
</select>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

This works because `<option>` creates an HTML element, not a string. The reducer returns an array of elements which can be rendered as HTML by React.